# how to fix opensuse GUI on VNC display?

Tags: x11, opensuse, vnc-viewer

our server has opensuse 12.1, whenever I try to access through VNC viewer the GUI of opensuse is appearing raw. I guess its the problem with X11 or X-windows. how do I fix this to get a better GUI for all the views? 
And also when we create a new user we need to modify the xstartup file to append startkde & to have a GUI. Is there a way that I can modify it at one place and xstartup is modified for all the new users created?

Thank you

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more clearly what "raw GUI" means? is it the resolution, no kde effects?
As to second part of your question - basically u don't need to start X session to create / set user accounts see the link [link](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/113091-how-create-user-console-graphic-interface.html) - get familiar with user* commands - it really speeds up the work. Cheers!